# Data packet sniffer in python

Tags: python

Every time I run my code I get this error and I am not sure why
**OSError: [WinError 10043] The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists**

```
import socket
import struct

def main():
    conn = socket .socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3) )
    while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65536)
        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)
        print('\nethernet Frame: ')
        print('Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}'.format(dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto))


#unpack ethernet frame
def ethernet_frame(data):
    dest_mac, src_mac, proto = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data [:14])
    return get_mac_addr(dest_mac), get_mac_addr(src_mac), socket.htons(proto), data[14:]

# Return formatted MQC address
def get_mac_addr(bytes_addr):
    bytes_str = map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_addr )
    return ':'.join(bytes_str).upper()

main()
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe you need the `ntohs` with Python.  It should be doing that for you.  The default value, `socket.IPPROTO_TCP` has the value 6, not `htons(6)`.  "3" should give you GGP.  Are you trying to get ethernet headers?  That needs `socket.AF_PACKET`.

Comment: Maybe the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for Windows sockets can shed light on some combination of configurations you have that just aren't compatible?

Comment: Also note that raw packet access has to be done in an elevated process.  Are you in an elevated shell?